# how to expand peek problem window in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When opening peek problem window (Alt-F8) I get a one line window with a very long horizontal scrollbar.

Is there a way to increase window height or maximize it?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+M opens up the problems window. It should show you the same content there.

Comment: Yes but again there is a very long horizontal scrolling.